# Filter results based on check boxes.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

- All
- 1 BHK
- 2 BHK
- 3 BHK
- 4 BHK
- 5 BHK

I want to filter results based on check boxes clicked, as I press these check boxes.

Auto ad check-box value in URL place of Bhk=1 Bhk,2Bhk.. search-result.php?ResidentalType=Sell&ResidentialProperties=Apartment&Bhk=&budget_from=&budget_to=&City=Ahmedabad+West&ResidentalPropertySubmit=GO

Answer (score 0):

Use a form to submit it

```
<form id="someformId" action="submitform.php" method="POST">

<input type="checkbox" name="bhk" value="1 BHK">1 BHK<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="bhk" value="2 BHK">2 BHK<br>
.....
.....
.....

</form>
```

and in **submitform.php** you can call the `$_POST['bhk']` to return values

Comment: i want to like this site refine search in side bar -  http://www.makaan.com/ahmedabad-property/residential-property-for-sale-in-ahmedabad-east/search-properties?SERP=List    when click on check box auto filter result according selecet check box

Comment: if you want to handle this with the help of javascript, you can build the url using jquery with checkbox onchecked event

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="frm1" name="frm1" action="submitform.php" method="POST">

<input type="checkbox" name="bhk[]" value="1 BHK">1 BHK
<input type="checkbox" name="bhk[]" value="2 BHK">2 BHK
<input type="checkbox" name="bhk[]" value="3 BHK">3 BHK
<input type="checkbox" name="bhk[]" value="4 BHK">4 BHK
<input type="checkbox" name="bhk[]" value="5 BHK">5 BHK

</form>
```

- Generate one form.
- Put the code inside that.
- Make an array of check-boxes with same name.
- Set action of form so that you can get data according.
- Get data using `$_POST['bhk']` variable.

Comment: i want to like this site refine search in side bar -  http://www.makaan.com/ahmedabad-property/residential-property-for-sale-in-ahmedabad-east/search-properties?SERP=List    when click on check box auto filter result according selecet check box

Comment: Use checked event using jquery, and you should use Unique ID of that check box to filter records accordingly.....